# Compare 2 lists while iterating through another list - Python

Tags: python, list, networkx

I have a list `source` which represents nodes in a network graph. I iterate through the nodes in `source` to obtain a sub-list of neighbouring nodes. At the same time, all neighbouring nodes are compared against another list `watch_list`.

I want to create a separate list `adjacent` that specifies whether the node in `source` has a neighbour in `watch_list`. See the code below:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

source = ['A','C','B','D','G','C','B','G']
target = ['B','T','G','A','T','B','H','V']
weight = [2, 1, 6, 6, 3, 3, 2, 1]
watch_list = ['H','D','T']

df = pd.DataFrame([source,target,weight])
df = df.transpose()
df.columns = ['source','target','weight']
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,'source','target','weight') 

adjacent = []
for i in source:
    for j in list(nx.all_neighbors(G, i)):
        if j in watch_list:
            adjacent.append('Y')
        else: adjacent.append('N') 

print(adjacent)
```

Running this code returns the following list:

```
>>> ['N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N']
```

The problem is that the code is iterating through the all the neighbours and appending 'Y' or 'N' with each iteration.

How can I control the flow to append 'Y' or 'N' only once, indicating that a node in `source` either has a neighbour on the `watch_list` ('Y'), or doesn't ('N').

It seems like a simple flow-control question, but I can't seem to get it right. 
Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and check if any neighbour is in your `watch_list`:

```
adjacent = []
for i in source:
    if any(x in watch_list for x in list(nx.all_neighbors(G, i))):
        adjacent.append('Y')
    else: 
        adjacent.append('N') 

print(adjacent)
```

Result:

```
['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y']
```

Answer (score 1):

This code produces a `'Y'` or `'N'` for each `j`:

```
for j in list(nx.all_neighbors(G, i)):
    if j in watch_list:
        adjacent.append('Y')
    else: adjacent.append('N')
```

If you just want to know if there is any `j` for which there is a neighbour, use `any`:

```
is_there_any = any(j in watch_list
                   for j in list(nx.all_neighbors(G, i)))
if is_there_any:
    adjacent.append('Y')
else:
    adjacent.append('N')
```

Or, I would rather do simply this:

```
adjacent = [any(j in watch_list
                for j in list(nx.all_neighbors(G, i)))
            for i in source]
# adjacent now holds booleans, rather than strings, but I think that is better
```